# How to use Ratingbar accurately?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've seen several tutorials on using RatingBar, but the problem persists.

[Ratingbar - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193834/ratingbar-how-to)

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150770/ratingbar-enviando-valor-para-textview-android

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206958/rating-arredonda-para-estrelas-fixas

I am developing an app in java, android studio, and I am trying to use the ratingbar.

The problem is that the stars are not being selected correctly ...
There are cases where I click on star2 and star3 is selected and so on.

```
<RatingBar

        android:id="@+id/rtbAval"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:padding="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtNomeAval"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />




        obs.setText(av.getObservacoes());

        nota.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                obs.setText(String.valueOf(rating));
            }
        });
```

Numbers below stars can use star count.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you to create only one rating bar, just for testing and check if it reproduces with only one rating bar. I've tried doing so and had no luck to reproduce what you saying.

Comment: @OrenZakay I only put one ratingBar and the end result was the same.
Ex: By clicking on two ... the result is 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any listener in order to get the value of rating. You can get it from getNumStars() method of RatingBar class. It will return the number of stars shown.

Comment: getNumStar returns the maximum number of stars and not the selected stars.

Comment: @JúlioCésarBindandi in that case, rtbAvl.getRating.toString() will work to give you the number of selected stars